# Prevent onbeforeunload from being called when clicking on mailto link

Tags: mailto, onbeforeunload

Is there anyway to prevent onbeforeunload from being called when clicking on mailto link in chrome.
In FF, Safari, IE it is working fine.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js">
        google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
        });

        function confirmExit() {
            return "Are you sure?";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="mailto:someone@somewhere.com?subject=test mail&body=Hello%20World">Mail Link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about a workaround?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    mailtoClicked = false;
    window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
    //Test if browser is Chrome
    if (/chrom(e|ium)/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())) {
        $('a[href^=mailto]').click(function() {mailtoClicked = true;});
    }
});

function confirmExit() {
    if (!mailtoClicked) {
        return "Are you sure?";
    } else {
        mailtoClicked = false;
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/robertc/fjyztnsr/).

Comment: @Qwertiy What about Firefox?  OP said it was working fine there.

Comment: Click mailto-link in FF, flag is set to true, no `onbeforeunload` event is fired. Now close the page: `onbeforeunload` is fired but ignored.

Comment: @Qwertiy [Seems to work fine in FF for me](https://jsfiddle.net/robertc/fjyztnsr/) once I corrected the typo.  Are you aware of [this recent change in `onbeforeunload` behaviour in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=636905)?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/akz0j0L2/ - click mailto then reload. In FF page will be reloaded without confirmation as is it supressed by the flag.

Comment: @Qwertiy OK, I see the problem.  Remove the `else`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proposed solutions that looks reasonable

http://www.ilovebonnie.net/2009/09/23/how-to-use-onbeforeunload-with-form-submit-buttons/

---

**UPDATE (link is dead) - Copied contents from Google Cache**

**How to Use onbeforeunload with Form Submit Buttons**

September 23rd, 2009 — Geekery

While doing some programming I came across an interesting predicament. While I understand it’s evil to make it hard for a user to leave a page, I’m not here to argue the merits (or lack thereof) of onbeforeunload.

On a particular form, we are forcing the browser to not cache the information to avoid potential AJAX/JavaScript problems if they should leave the form and come back as browsers don’t all act the same (eg IE leaves checkboxes checked but doesn’t remember changes that have occurred to the page due to JavaScript). As such, we warn our users when they’re about to leave the order form to let them know they’ll need to fill it in again.

The function was simple enough:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    return "You are about to leave this order form. You will lose any information...";
}
```

Unfortunately, this would also be triggered if the user submitted the form which, is obviously not what we want. After searching around on the Internet I came across a simple solution that I thought I would share:

```
// Create a variable that can be set upon form submission
var submitFormOkay = false;
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    if (!submitFormOkay) {
        return "You are about to leave this order form. You will lose any information...";
    }
}
```

Since onclick appears to register before onsubmit when clicking a submit button, we can add a little variable declaration to our submit button so that submitFormOkay will be set to true before the form submission happens:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit_button" onclick="submitFormOkay = true;">
```

Comment: Broken link...  Not useful in 2017!

Comment: @ForguesR I have copied in the contents from Google cache so it is now useful again!